# Explicitly cast a type that involves a specific function item type

Tags: function, types, rust, coercion

Here is an example:

```
use std::iter::Filter;
use std::slice::Iter;

fn test(xs: &[i32]) -> Filter<Iter<i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
    fn nothing(_: &&i32) -> bool { false }

    let ys = xs.iter().filter(nothing);
    ys
}

fn main () {
}
```

Compilation fails with:

```
src/main.rs:8:5: 8:7 error: mismatched types:
 expected `core::iter::Filter<core::slice::Iter<'_, i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool>`,
    found `core::iter::Filter<core::slice::Iter<'_, i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool {test1::nothing}>`
(expected fn pointer,
    found fn item) [E0308]
src/main.rs:8     ys
                  ^~
```

This is because the inferred type of `ys` has the [type of a specific function item in it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#function-types-for-specific-items). In this particular case the issue is easy to fix: one can either explicitly specify the type without the function item in the binding, or avoid the `let` altogether.

Both of these work:

```
fn test(xs: &[i32]) -> Filter<Iter<i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
    fn nothing(_: &&i32) -> bool { false }

    let ys: Filter<Iter<i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> = xs.iter().filter(nothing);
    ys
}
```

```
fn test(xs: &[i32]) -> Filter<Iter<i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
    fn nothing(_: &&i32) -> bool { false }

    xs.iter().filter(nothing)
}
```

Therefore, as the Reference says, indeed Rust is capable of performing this coercion itself. But what if the code was more complex and I had to perform this cast manually? How would I do this?

In this case `as` won’t work, and `transmute` seems to be an overkill, although, I believe, it would do the job.

Answer (score 3):

You can actually cast using `as`:

```
fn test(xs: &[i32]) -> Filter<Iter<i32>, fn(&&i32) -> bool> {
    fn nothing(_: &&i32) -> bool { false }

    let ys = xs.iter().filter(nothing as fn(&&i32) -> bool);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    ys
}
```

However you need to use `as` to change the function's type, not the `Filter` type, as `as` is not allowed to change arbitrary types.

---

Personally, I consider the necessity of the cast a short-coming and hope that type inference will improve to the point it becomes unnecessary. The fact that it works for a direct return is a red-herring, it should probably work with an intermediate value too.